# Precision and Recall in YOLOv5

Tags: yolov5

At the end of every YOLOv5 training epoch, you get an output like this:

```
Class     Images  Instances          P          R      mAP50   mAP50-95: 100%|██████████| 9/9 [00:04<00:00,  1.93it/s]
                   all        262        175      0.861      0.686      0.735      0.317
```

I assume that `P` and `R` mean precision and recall. But my question is, at what IoU threshold and what confidence threshold? Don't these parameters have to be set to properly define precision and recall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found on this link: https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/9904